# Validate and get the user using the jwt token inside a view or consumer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am using [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for the REST API. Also, for JSON web token authentication I am using [django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt). After a successful login, the user is provided with a token. I have found how to [verify a token](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#verify-token) with the api call, but is there any way to validate the token inside a view and get the user of that token, similar to request.user?

I need it to validate inside the consumer when using [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```
def ws_connect(message):
    params = parse_qs(message.content["query_string"])
    if b"token" in params:
        token = params[b"token"][0]

    # validate the token and get the user object

    # create an object with that user
```

Comment: Do you have permission added to you View? I am assuming your view is created using one the view classes of DRF

Comment: @Swapnil Yes. Actually I need it in the consumers when using django channels. I have updated the question.

Comment: I have not used django-rest-frameork-jwt library but going through their doc it looks like if you have setup the library correctly, they should set the `request.user` in case of `rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was about to validate the token and get the user by importing VerifyJSONWebTokenSerializer class.

```
from rest_framework_jwt.serializers import VerifyJSONWebTokenSerializer

data = {'token': token}
valid_data = VerifyJSONWebTokenSerializer().validate(data)
user = valid_data['user']
```

Hope this helps any body like me.

Comment: I am able to authorize my user but still django rest framework is saying unauthorized user

Answer (score 6):

Use `TokenBackend` instead of `VerifyJSONWebTokenSerializer`

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.backends import TokenBackend
token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', " ").split(' ')[1]
data = {'token': token}
        try:
            valid_data = TokenBackend(algorithm='HS256').decode(token,verify=False)
            user = valid_data['user']
            request.user = user
        except ValidationError as v:
            print("validation error", v)
```

Comment: Using this code I always get `TokenBackendError: Token is invalid or expired`, even for a valid fresh token. This happens indistinctively when creating the backend by hand or getting it from `AccessToken.get_token_backend()`. Seems related to how `jwt` handles payload. Anyway, having the object AccessToken created you can get information with `AccessToken.payload` member.

Comment: What does the `verify=False` do?